# The DataBase is Locked..inserting values in table using a Loop

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am making a restaurant management application in java using sqlite database. In application when order confirm button is pressed the application is supposed to insert into order table, insert into order dishes/Items and minuses the quantity of each ingredient used in dish that is added in an order..
When i tried following code it says "SQLExcption:The Database is Locked "

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select dishId from dishes where dishName = '" + orderTable.getValueAt(i, 1) + "'");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int dishId = rs.getInt("dishId");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into orderDishes values(?,?,?)");
            pst.setInt(1, currentOrderNumber);
            pst.setInt(2, dishId);
            pst.setInt(3, (int) orderTable.getValueAt(i, 0));
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select ingId , quantity from dishIng where dishId = '" + dishId + "'");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                ingReducedQuantity = rs.getInt("quantity");
                ingId = rs.getInt("ingId");
                pst1 = con1.prepareStatement("select qunatity from ingriedients where ingId = '" + ingId + "'");
                rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
                previousQuantity = rs1.getInt("qunatity");
                pst1.close();
                rs1.close();
                con1.commit();
                newQuantity = previousQuantity - ingReducedQuantity;
                // Here it gives exception
                pst1 = con1.prepareStatement("update ingriedients set  qunatity = '" + newQuantity + "' where ingId = '" + ingId + "'");
                pst1.executeUpdate();
                con1.commit();
            }
        }
```

I think exception comes in while loop before updating ingriedients table but i don,t know why..plz suggest some solution..

Comment: You have this typo: _select qunatity from..._ You're also misspelling `ingredients`, but you're doing that consistently, so perhaps that's not a problem.

Comment: Actually the column name is qunatity  so its not a typo ..and also its not syntax error it's some kind of connection problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before every connection and statements you need to close any privious connection and statement
because **sqlite** does not support more than one active transactions, so before the first **con1.prepareStatement** (in the while loop ) in your code, close other previous connections and statements also, I mean **pst**, **con**, etc

Comment: "sqlite does not support more than one connection" this fact did the trick though i don't have to close other connections before every new statement..

Comment: SQLite actually does support multiple connections; it does not allow multiple active transactions when one tries to write.